# C# Windows Form - How to refresh the datagridview after CellEndEdit event

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a Datagridview that updates using a Datasource. I'm trying to refresh the Datagridview after the CellEndEdit event. Everything works perfectly, but Datagridview is not refreshing. Below is my c# code.

```
private void GridDetails_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == GridDetails.Columns["Name"].Index)
        {
            string ID = GridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            string Name = GridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();


            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(.........)) // SqlConnection
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                        cmd.CommandText = "Update MyTable SET Name=@Name,LastModifiedDate=GETDATE() WHERE RecID=@ID";//Update Query
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                  

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                        GridDetails.Refresh(); // this is not working
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Refresh() doesn't do what you think it does. It is about painting the control, not about refreshing the data. If the data has changed you need to re-bind it.

Comment: If you configure your DB Provider objects correctly there is no need to refresh, re paint or rebind when data is changed in a bound control.  Just update the DB once in a while.

Comment: @Crowcoder Is there any way we can update the current raw instead of changing the entire Datagridview because I have more the 20k rows in my Datagridview.

Comment: Yes, you can manipulate the value of any cell in any row individually through the DataGridViewRow and DataGridViewCell properties. However, > 20K rows is user overload. Consider paging results. Also, consider using the features available to [data bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) instead of constantly accessing rows and cells.

Comment: What is the datasource for your datagridview? Depending of it is a table or query you may need to rebind or requery after the query is excecuted.

Comment: @Kevin My Datasource is a query. Thanks

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Thank You for the feedback

Comment: @sura If you have a DataSource instance between grid and a DataTable, and if you have problem with realtime display and bidirectionnal matching, you can use [ResetBindings(false)](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings). But if you have a BindingList I recommend you to use this [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView) else you could need to rebind all. But that said, I don't understand the problem: if you edit with the grid and update the DB, that's an unusual pattern but fine. Why using a SQL Update in this event handler?

Comment: The DGV does not get repainted automatically after a change so the view doesn't get changed.  The trick is to set the datasource to null and then back to original object so DGV gets repainted.

Comment: What *are* you actually trying to do? There doesn't appear to be anything to refresh. "If the user edits the ListPrice column, send an update to the DB" - what about that process needs anything to be changed?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Updating data in a Grid and then update the DB, why is that an unusual pattern ? Just curious

Comment: You will then need to set your datasource to null and rebind.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I'm using SQL update in this event handler because if the user Edits the cell value, I need to update the table and display the last modified date from the DB. I updated my code.

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated my code. if the user Edits the Name cell value, I need to update the table and display the last modified date from the DB.

Comment: There is a lot to be referenced here, but...have you tryed "dataGrid.RefreshEdit();"? And also, check if the values of gridViewEntidades.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem are updated (wich I doubt) and work from there...is your update is done without errors, update the DataBoundItem.